# How to make the popup on this piechart appear on click instead of onhover?

Tags: javascript, jquery

http://thaint.net/chart/

How to make the popup on this piechart appear on click instead of onhover ?

Comment: show what you have tried..

Comment: I haven't tried anything as I don't know js.

Comment: @rowdy Please refer to the jqchart plugin documetation that you are using in your code... see here: [link](http://www.jqchart.com/docs/jquery/#!/guide/Tooltips)

Answer (score 0):

Well it's quite difficult to say something without any reference as you have not posted any code here. Anyway, the code for this functionality must be written by `hover` event of chart. You need to change it to `click` event. For this you need to dig into JS library on which or by which this chart is working.

The link you provided is working on [jqchart](http://www.jqchart.com). So you need to check thier API documents for your goal.